# How do I write a unit test for post request flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Went over the docs at [Official Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking). It's reference was in get requests, I'm trying to mock Test for registration screen,Here's my **service class** below,

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> register(String email, String password,
      String name, String locale, context) async {
    var result;
    final Map<String, dynamic> registrationData = {
      "usermail": email,
      "password": password,
      "userProfile": {"name": name, "locale": locale}
    };
    _registeredInStatus = Status.Authenticating;
    Response response = await post(
      Uri.parse(Provider.of<Env>(context, listen: false).api + AppUrl.signup),
      body: json.encode(registrationData),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );

    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      result = {
        'status': true,
        'message': 'Successfully registered',
      };
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      _registeredInStatus = Status.Registered;
      result = {
        'status': false,
        'message': json.decode(response.body)['errors']
      };
    }

    print("SIGNUP${result}");
    return result;
  }
```

And here's my test.

```
@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
void main() {
  group('Register -', () {

    test('when register called returns 200', () async {
      AuthProvider auth = AuthProvider();
      final client = MockClient();
      dynamic context;
      dynamic result = {
        'status': true,
        'message': 'Successfully registered',
      };
      when(client.post(Uri.parse("https://testapi.io/api/mockapi/register'"),
              body: anyNamed('body')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(result, 200));

      expect(
          await auth.register(
              'username@gmail.com', 'abcdWW1', 'MyName', 'locale', context),
          result);
    });
  })};
```

So how do I write a post request for the test the authorization tokens

Comment: Do you get an error with this current test set up?

Comment: Add what is the result for this test and what is the expected result. anyway, you probably have a typo here `when(client.post(Uri.parse("https://testapi.io/api/mockapi/register'"),` there  is an extra `'` after the URL